# Find element by class and toggle it

Tags: javascript

I have inside my html code repeating elements like this:

```
 <li>
   <a class="synth-faq-trigger" href="#0">Link</a>
     <div class="synth-faq-content">
        <p class="filler">Text</p>
     </div> <!-- synth-faq-content -->
 </li>
```

and I use the following command so I can *toggle* the class `'content-visible'` that will make this element slide to reveal the contents of `<p>`, in this case **Text**.

What I am trying to do is before doing this in my code, find the previous element that had a class of `'content-visible'` and toggle it, so only one element remains visible at all times.

```
$(this).next('.synth-faq-content').slideToggle(200).end().parent('li').toggleClass('content-visible');
```

I tried various things lastly being

```
$(this).closest('synth-faq-trigger').next().find('.synth-faq-content').toggleClass('content-visible');
```

that has no effect at all. Moreover the suggestions from w3school on finding an element by class failed all together.

How can I make sure that I find all my items containing `'content-visible'` and I remove this class from them?

Comment: Can't you just remove the class `content-visible` from ALL the elements before adding it to another element?

Comment: Or store a reference to it when toggled

Comment: Well the thing is that every few months or so I start learning a new language, I do so by doing small projects and I just started js so I am not sure how to do that. since I failed to even find that one element I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sibling relation like

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  var $li = $(this).next('.synth-faq-content').slideToggle(200).closest('li').toggleClass('content-visible');
  
  $('li.content-visible').not($li).removeClass('content-visible').find('.synth-faq-content').slideUp();
})
```

```css
.content-visible > a {
  color: green;
}
.synth-faq-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="synth-faq-trigger" href="#0">Link</a>
    <div class="synth-faq-content">
      <p class="filler">Text</p>
    </div>
    <!-- synth-faq-content -->
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="synth-faq-trigger" href="#0">Link</a>
    <div class="synth-faq-content">
      <p class="filler">Text</p>
    </div>
    <!-- synth-faq-content -->
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="synth-faq-trigger" href="#0">Link</a>
    <div class="synth-faq-content">
      <p class="filler">Text</p>
    </div>
    <!-- synth-faq-content -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this works perfectly, but because my own items have a lot more text, sometimes if you click at an item below the one currently open, and because that last item will close freeing up the space, it might drag the item you just clicked above the viewport. So the item you just clicked and you are expecting to see has disappeared somewhere above the viewport, and you must now scroll up to see it. I found `element.scrollIntoView({block: "end", behavior: "smooth"});` but it had no effect. Is there anything that can be done for that?

Answer (score 3):

I notice you are already using hash links in your example code, and because of this, you can achieve what you are trying without any JavaScript. Browsers already have functionality to handle displaying elements depending on the hash target, so let's exploit this browser feature rather than implementing it again in JavaScript.

## Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g105b/cj5fscah/

The `href` of the anchor is to a hash link, which will be put into the URL bar of the browser. Each `li` element has an ID that corresponds to the hash targets, and using the `:target` CSS selector, you can style elements differently depending on what the hash is.

With some fancy CSS you can add animations too, that will perform much better than any JavaScript can.

```
<ul>
    <li id="0">
       <a class="synth-faq-trigger" href="#0">Link</a>
         <div class="synth-faq-content">
            <p class="filler">Text for one</p>
         </div> <!-- synth-faq-content -->
     </li>
    <li id="1">
       <a class="synth-faq-trigger" href="#1">Link</a>
         <div class="synth-faq-content">
            <p class="filler">Text for two</p>
         </div> <!-- synth-faq-content -->
     </li>
    <li id="2">
       <a class="synth-faq-trigger" href="#2">Link</a>
         <div class="synth-faq-content">
            <p class="filler">Text for three</p>
         </div> <!-- synth-faq-content -->
     </li>
</ul>

ul {
    width: 320px;
}
li {
    background: #aaf;
}

.synth-faq-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    transition: height 200ms ease-in-out;
}
li:target .synth-faq-content {
    height: 3em;
}
```

Edit: if you still need to manipulate the class names, a simple piece of JavaScript can trigger when the hash changes to accomplish having a class added to the correct LI element.

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e) {
    // Remove all .content-visible elements:
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".content-visible"), function(li) {
        li.classList.remove("content-visible");
    });

    // Add .content-visible to the li that contains the clicked anchor:
    document.querySelector("a[href='" + location.hash + "']").parentElement.classList.add("content-visible");
});
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g105b/cj5fscah/1/

Comment: smooth  transitiion and with css only , WOW !

Comment: The fact that you did this with css only and it looks so smooth is amazing, unfortunately I cannot change the way my code works because I need the class name to exist as there are various icons that depend on it. Up-voting for the very interesting info hidden in your answer.

Comment: @dearn44 To answer your question I have added the necessary JavaScript to maintain the `content-visible` class name.